# I want to open another web site in my component. Using deep linking in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have to use **Deep linking**. Tell me what should i do?

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [ { path: 'hi',
redirectTo: '/http://www.sunbeaminfo.com/',
pathMatch: 'full'
}];
```

**app.component.html**

```
<a href="/hi" routerLinkActive="active">demo</a>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: https://divami.com/blog/deep-linking-angular/

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow.  You can probably improve your question.  It looks like you are showing us what you are trying to do, but we need to know what kind of output this gives - do you get an error or a console message?  In what way does it fail to work?  Also you might want to give this a read:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @AdritaSharma Your link points to angularJS

Answer (score 1):

Using the `Angular Router` for linking to external website is a good idea because you are able to call different `routing guard` doing so.

That being said, the easiest way to route to an external website is to use a `Resolve` guard.

In your route you define a route like this:

```
{
    path: 'myExternalLink/:url',
    resolve: { url: ExternalUrlNavigator },
    component: EmptyComponent // Just need a component. I don't know if redirect would     work here
}
```

Declare your brand new `Resolver` in the `providers` section of you `AppModule` like so:

```
...,
providers: [
    ExternalUrlNavigator
]
```

Then create your new `Resolver`

```
@Injectable()
export class ExternalUrlNavigator implements Resolve<void> {
    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): void {
        const url = route.params['url'];
        window.open(url, '_self');
    }
}
```

To use it you can give it as a parameter to the `router` as `this.router.navigate(['/myExternalLink`, {url: ''}]);`

And directly in the template

`<a [routerLink]="['/myExternalLink', {url: 'http://sunbeam.com'}]">Link to sunbeam</a>`.

and voilà!

More info on

[Window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)

[Resolver](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve)

[Routing guards](https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards)

Comment: in 'url' variable which url pass in that sunbeam.com or something else..  And in <a href="/...'>demo</a> // what should pass here

Comment: There you go, I updated my answer. Note that I didn't tested it so it might be a bit off.

Comment: core.js:9110 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'myExternalLink;url=http:%2F%2Fwww.sunbeaminfo.com%2F'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'myExternalLink;url=http:%2F%2Fwww.sunbeaminfo.com%2F'

Comment: Can you provide the line where this comes from? the one with `<a>` where you call `routerLink`

Comment: I found this: https://medium.com/@adrianfaciu/using-the-angular-router-to-navigate-to-external-links-15cc585b7b88

Comment: @SalmanPathan Did you found what you were seaking? If so please leave a thumbs up on this answer to let me know.